# Assign command to a set of buttons in grid through style

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

Is it possible in `silverlight` to assign a same command to a set of buttons in a grid through style? or assign it at a common place instead of repeating?

I mean something like using this -

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command1}"/>
</Style>
```

instead of -

```
<Button Command="{Binding Command1}"/> 
<Button Command="{Binding Command1}"/> 
<Button Command="{Binding Command1}"/> 
           ...
<Button Command="{Binding Command1}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. In a simple way you can add a Style to the `Resources` and use it as a `StaticResource`. Assuming that `Command1` belongs to the `ViewModel` you are binding to the `Window`. If not, provide proper path to the `Command1` to bind it properly.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="buttonCommandStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Command1}" />
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then use it as the `Style` for your `Button`

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource buttonCommandStyle}" />
```

Comment: ...and then he has to repeat the style assignment ad nauseam. And the Binding Path will always be evaluated against the DataContext property if no source is specified.

Comment: Using binding in Setter is causing  a XamlParseException

Comment: @Bells Binding in Setter is introduced in SilverLight 5. Are you sure your Binding string `Source` and `Path` are proper

Comment: He is using the windowsPhone silverlight version, that does not allow for Silverlight 5 features.

Comment: @Martin I didn't notice the `windowsphone-8` tag.

Comment: @Vishnu Prasad: Sorry, I missed to add the tag initially. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Bells that's fine. I don't know much about windows phone. Wish i could find the right answer

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.95).aspx).

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MyItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding MyButtonItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding Command1}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `Binding` will be evaluated against each item, therefore you have several ways of providing the command instance:

- you could place the same command instance as a public property in each itemInstance
- you could set a source or relativeSource for the `Binding` to have it evaluated against the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl` instead of against each item: `{Binding Path=DataContext.Command1, ElementName=MyItemsControl}`